# Asp.Net core 2.1 AuthorizeAttribute fails [using jwt for authentication, which seems to pass]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

The jwt token get validated but the Authorize attribute (simple usage, no roles or other stuff specified) still blocks the request.
Note that i don't have any code that would control the AutorizeAttribute behavior (so everything should go with what the framework has)

From logs:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55000/api/Companies/GetSummaries  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "GetSummaries", controller = "Companies"}. Executing action MyTestApplication.Controllers.Companies.CompaniesController.GetSummaries (MyTestApplication)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MyTestApplication.Controllers.Companies.CompaniesController.GetSummaries (MyTestApplication) in 16.5934ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 25.4438ms 401 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:55000/api/Customers/Get?includeInactive=false  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Customers"}. Executing action MyTestApplication.Controllers.Customers.CustomersController.Get (MyTestApplication)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MyTestApplication.Controllers.Customers.CustomersController.Get (MyTestApplication) in 9.6949ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 20.3964ms 401 
The thread 0x4764 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Jwt config in app start (not sure if this helps as it seems to work):

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwtBearerOptions =>
    {
        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtTokenCreator.Secret);

        jwtBearerOptions.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

        jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes),

                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = JwtTokenCreator.AppIssuer,

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = JwtTokenCreator.AppAudience,

                ValidateLifetime = true, 

                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(JwtTokenCreator.ExpirationTimeInMinutes)                                            
    };
});
```

Also the token generation:

```
public string GenerateToken(Guid sessionId)
{
        var symmetricKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Secret);

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, sessionId.ToString()), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"User") }),

                Expires = now.AddMinutes(ExpirationTimeInMinutes),
                Audience = AppAudience,
                Issuer = AppIssuer,

                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)

        };

        var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);
        return token;
}
```

Comment: How do you make a request to your endpoint? I want to see how you set your bearer token. Also take a look at [this post](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/10/19/policy-based-authorization-using-asp-net-core-2-and-json-web-token-jwt/), it has JWT with Asp.Net Core usage with code sample.

Comment: @HamidMosalla thanks for your reply, i got this thing working by setting the schema on the attribute like you did - [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]; however at some point i would have to remove it if i want to use multiple authentication scheme or other variations [different authentication scheme]

Comment: You can combine multiple schemes as detailed in [Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute).